# Is it acceptable to reheat frozen food?

Tags: reheating

If I make a frozen meal and then save the leftovers in the refrigerator, is it OK to reheat it the next day in the microwave? Since it's already been frozen (or freeze dried, whatever they do), it seems like it may not be the best thing to do.

And I realize this is hardly "cooking", but I figure it loosely fits under the site's umbrella.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you mean like a potpie or a TV dinner? Yes you're fine, go for it.

If you're really worried about it here is the rule. (been a few years since I took serveSafe)

When reheating foods you want the internal temperature to reach 165 degrees F. (74C) for 15 seconds. In practice (at home NOT at the restaurant) just get it nice and hot.

Note: Homemade foods generally need to be carefully reheated but not frozen dinners etc. They cook them pretty good at the factory.

Comment: +1 Good enough answer for me. Just beware that you heat (and cool) as fast as you can. If you leave your food out of the fridge a couple of hours you could have a problem. Take care with the elderly and the young.